# Using variable as a prefix in the select statement

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a source XML file with dynamic (generated) namespace prefix but static URI for that namespace. I need to get this generated prefix by URI and use it in my XSL style sheet.

**Source XML:**

```
<rdf:RDF
        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
        xmlns:j.4="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#">
    <rdf:Description>
        <j.4:prefLabel>TestNode</j.4:prefLabel>
    </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

**XSL Stylesheet :**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
                xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
                xmlns:j.4="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsl skos rdf xsd "
                version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
                indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="skosprefix" select="name(//rdf:RDF/namespace::*[. = 'http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#'])" />

    <xsl:template match="//rdf:RDF/rdf:Description">
        <node>
            <xsl:value-of select="j.4:prefLabel"/>
        </node>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So in my XSL stylesheet (select statement) I would like to use something like **$skosprefix:prefLabel** instead of **j.4:prefLabel** to get the resulting XML:

```xml
<node>TestNode</node>
```

How can I achieve it using XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like

```
<xsl:value-of select="*[name() = 'j.4:prefLabel'"/>
```

---

If you have the namespace in a variable (here, `nsuri`), then you can use this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="*[namespace-uri() = $nsuri and local-name() = 'prefLabel']"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunately it will not solve the problem. I didn't want to use 'j.4' in my select statement because it's "unknown" in advance. The only thing is known is the URI of that namespace.

Comment: Great! Thank you! It works as expected, but you've missed a closing bracket in the select statement. Could you please add it before I accept your answer?